# Why SIFT costs more time with fewer octave layers?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, time-complexity, sift

I'm using SIFT feature detector in [OpenCV 4.5.2](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d7/d60/classcv_1_1SIFT.html). By tuning the `nOctaveLayers` parameter in `cv::SIFT::create()`, I get these results from `detectAndCompute()`:

| nOctaveLayers | KeyPoints | Time Cost (ms) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1026 | 63.41 |
| 2 | 1795 | 45.07 |
| 3 | 2043 | 45.74 |
| 4 | 2173 | 47.83 |
| 5 | 2224 | 51.86 |

To my understanding, there should be less computation with fewer octave layers, but **why SIFT costs significantly more time with only 1 octave layer**?

I also tested `detect()` and `compute()` separately, and they both cost more time when `nOctaveLayers` is 1, which confuses me a lot.

The test image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHNHN.jpg) (from TUM open dataset). Thanks ahead for any help.

---

[Edit for @Micka] My test code:

```cpp
const int test_num = 100;
const int layers = 5;
cout << "layers: " << layers << endl;

auto sift = SIFT::create(0, layers);
vector<KeyPoint> kps;
Mat descs;

auto t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
for (int i = 0; i < test_num; ++i)
    sift->detectAndCompute(img_src, noArray(), kps, descs);
auto t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
cout << "num of kps: " << kps.size() << endl;
cout << "avg time cost: " << chrono::duration<double>(t2 - t1).count() * 1e3 / test_num << endl;
```

For each `nOctaveLayers` configuration, I change `layers` value in the code, recompile & run & record the result.

Comment: can you show the code how you tested? If all tests are in a single code, can you try in reverse order (starting with 5 octaves)? Maybe initialization time is currently only in test 1? In addition it is always good to use the average runtime of N runtimes, because ms measurement quality is quite system dependent.

Comment: test procedure looks ok to me. In addition the time cost is increasing between nOctaves=2 till 5, so I too would assume that nOctaves=1 should have less time cost. Maybe you will have to check whether nOctaves=1 has a special meaning in this implementation. Do you know whether using more octaves only adds additional keypoints to the case of less octaves, or whether some keypoints can be replaced by higher octave? If the latter is the case, maybe keypoints in higher octaves are cheaper (smaller descriptor window) and nOctaves=1 has no chance to identify the "real" size/octave of a keypoint.

Comment: I checked this [code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/sift.dispatch.cpp) roughly but did not find anything special about choosing `nOctaves=1`. Imho it should have less time cost like Micka said. Maybe you could start an issue on the github and ask there. These people are closer to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of profiling, I finally found out the reason: `GaussianBlur`.

The pipeline of SIFT algorithm is:

1. Create initial image: convert data type of source image to `float`, double the resolution, and do `GaussianBlur` (sigma=1.56)
2. Build gaussian pyramid
3. Find key points: build DoG pyramid and find scale space extrema
4. Calculate descriptors

The num of octaves is calculated according to image resolution (see [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/features2d/src/sift.dispatch.cpp#L503)). And `nOctaveLayers` controls num of layers (`nOctaveLayers + 3` for GaussianPyramid) in each octave.

Indeed, when `nOctaveLayers` increases, nums of layers and keypoints both increase. As a result, time cost of step 3 & 4 increases. However, in parallel computation, this time increment is not very remarkable (several milliseconds).

In contrast, **the step 2 costs more than half of the total time**. It costs 25.27 ms (in 43.49 ms) when `nOctaveLayers` is 3, and 51.16 ms (in 63.10 ms) when `nOctaveLayers` is 1. So, why is this happening?

**Because the sigma for `GaussianBlur()` increases faster when layers are fewer, and it's critical for the time consumed by `GaussianBlur()`**. See test below:

```cpp
vector<double> sig1 = { 1.6, 2.77128, 5.54256, 11.0851 };
vector<double> sig3 = { 1.6, 1.22627, 1.54501, 1.94659, 2.45255, 3.09002 };
vector<double> sig5 = { 1.6, 0.9044, 1.03888, 1.19336, 1.37081, 1.57465, 1.8088, 2.07777 };

auto blurTest = [](const vector<double>& sigs, const string& label) {
    const int test_num = 100;
    auto t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < test_num; ++i) {
        vector<Mat> pyr;
        pyr.resize(sigs.size());
        pyr[0] = Mat::zeros(960, 1280, CV_32FC1);
        for (size_t i = 1; i < sigs.size(); ++i)
            GaussianBlur(pyr[i - 1], pyr[i], Size(), sigs[i], sigs[i]);
    }
    auto t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto time = chrono::duration<double>(t2 - t1).count() * 1e3 / test_num;
    cout << label << ": " << time << " ms\n";
};

blurTest(sig1, "1");
blurTest(sig3, "3");
blurTest(sig5, "5");

/* output:
1: 45.3958 ms
3: 28.5943 ms
5: 31.4827 ms
*/
```

The code above simulates [`buildGaussianPyramid()`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/features2d/src/sift.dispatch.cpp#L193) when `nOctaveLayers` is 1, 3, and 5. The sigma values are from `cv::SIFT` calculation. This explains why SIFT costs much more time when `nOctaveLayers` is 1.